# Apache Tika and Apache Solr integration through Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, solr, apache-tika

I am trying to integrate Apache tika and Apache Solr so that I can index my parse data. I'm using Solr version 4.3.1 and Tika version as 2.11.6.

The code which I am following are like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


import java.io.IOException;


import java.io.InputStream;


import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;


import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;


import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;


import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;


import org.apache.tika.metadata.DublinCore;


import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;


import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes;


import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;


import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;


import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;


import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;


import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;


import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Main {

    private static SolrServer solr;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {

        try {
            solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/"); //create solr connection

            //solr.deleteByQuery( "*:*" ); //delete everything in the index; good for testing

            //location of source documents
            //later this will be switched to a database

            String path = "C:\\content\\";

            String file_html = path + "mobydick.htm";

            String file_txt = path + "/home/ben/abc.warc";



            String file_pdf = path + "callofthewild.pdf";

            processDocument(file_html);

            processDocument(file_txt);

            processDocument(file_pdf);

            solr.commit(); //after all docs are added, commit to the index

            //now you can search at http://localhost:8983/solr/browse
        }
        catch  (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }           
    }

    private static void processDocument(String pathfilename)  {

        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(pathfilename));

            //use Apache Tika to convert documents in different formats to plain text
            ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(10*1024*1024);

            Metadata meta = new Metadata();

            Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

 //handles documents in different formats:
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();   
            parser.parse(input, textHandler, meta, context); //convert to plain text

            //collect metadata and content from Tika and other sources

            //document id must be unique, use guide
        UUID guid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        String docid = guid.toString();

            //Dublin Core metadata (partial set)
            String doctitle = meta.get(DublinCore.TITLE);
            String doccreator = meta.get(DublinCore.CREATOR); 

            //other metadata
            String docurl = pathfilename; //document url

            //content
            String doccontent = textHandler.toString();

            //call to index
            indexDocument(docid, doctitle, doccreator, docurl, doccontent);
        }

        catch  (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    private static void indexDocument(String docid, String doctitle, String doccreator, String docurl, String doccontent)  {

        try {

            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

            doc.addField("id", docid);

            //map metadata fields to default schema
            //location: path\solr-4.7.2\example\solr\collection1\conf\schema.xml

            //Dublin Core
            //thought: schema could be modified to use Dublin Core

            doc.addField("title", doctitle);

            doc.addField("author", doccreator);

            //other metadata


            doc.addField("url", docurl);

            //content (and text)
            //per schema, the content field is not indexed by default, used for returning and highlighting document content
            //the schema "copyField" command automatically copies this to the "text" field which is indexed

            doc.addField("content", doccontent);

            //indexing
            //when a field is indexed, like "text", Solr will handle tokenization, stemming, removal of stopwords etc, per the schema defn

            //add to index

            solr.add(doc);  
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}     } }
```

The **Error** I got

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
        at Main.main(Main.java:28)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException


    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be Tika related, so I would focus on Solr.

Specifically on how you included Solr libraries and its dependencies. If you pulled them through Maven, they should have worked. But if you did it manually, perhaps you missed one or two.

Specifically, the error message is about a missing class that is distributed with Apache Commons HTTP (client) library. Perhaps are missing it in dependencies or on the classpath.

Comment: I add all my dependency through maven, can you tell me how i can Connect this code with solr server.

Comment: Well, the error talks about missing library. You have to fix that first.